# What is the best approach to deploying to multiple servers using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkinsfile, jenkins-blueocean

Trying to figure out the best approach for deploying to multiple servers using Jenkins Blue Ocean pipeline.  We will have six servers in development, six in QA, six in Staging, and six in production.  Should I put the list of the servers in a config file and store in git or is there a plug-in or something within Jenkins that stores host names?  All feedback is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Matrix project plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-project/)?

> **Multi-Configuration Projects**
>
> A multi-configuration project is useful for instances where your
> builds will make many similar build steps, and you would otherwise be
> duplicating steps.
>
> **Configuration matrix**
>
> The Configuration Matrix allows you to specify what steps to
> duplicate, and create a multiple-axis graph of the type of builds to
> create.

[Welcome to the Matrix](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/) is an excellent reference doc.

Example (from [the blog](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/)) - Pipeline for multiple platforms and browsers

> ```
> Jenkinsfile
>
> pipeline {
>     agent none
>     stages {
>         stage('BuildAndTest') {
>             matrix {
>                 agent any
>                 axes {
>                     axis {
>                         name 'PLATFORM'
>                         values 'linux', 'windows', 'mac'
>                     }
>                     axis {
>                         name 'BROWSER'
>                         values 'firefox', 'chrome', 'safari', 'edge'
>                     }
>                 }
>                 stages {
>                     stage('Build') {
>                         steps {
>                             echo "Do Build for ${PLATFORM} - ${BROWSER}"
>                         }
>                     }
>                     stage('Test') {
>                         steps {
>                             echo "Do Test for ${PLATFORM} - ${BROWSER}"
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a minimal matrix example (perhaps using the declarative pipeline format?) for posterity? the links you reference might break.